# Understanding WAL Lag Query

Tags: postgresql, debezium

After scaling my API down to `0` instances, I still see a non-0 for `bytes_behind`.

```
user=> SELECT slot_name,
       pg_wal_lsn_diff(
          pg_current_wal_lsn(),
          restart_lsn
       ) AS bytes_behind,
       active,
       wal_status
FROM pg_replication_slots
WHERE wal_status <> 'lost'
ORDER BY restart_lsn;
            slot_name             | bytes_behind | active | wal_status 
----------------------------------+--------------+--------+------------
app_publisher_connector |          440 | t      | reserved
(1 row)
```

No rows are being `INSERT` to my database as a result of the API being scaled down.

Does a non-0 `bytes_behind` indicate that the `replication_slot` has not fully caught up?

I want to know a way to measure when the replication slot is fully caught up.

Comment: A non-zero bytes_behind indicates that the replication slot is not fully caught up. Regular monitoring of this value, along with the slot's active status, can help you manage replication health. In scenarios where no replication lag is acceptable, you'll want to ensure that the bytes_behind reaches and stays at zero, indicating real-time replication without lag.